# An equivalent for "Transform.RotateAround" BUT NON incremental ?? exact angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i would like to rotate an object around an other object just like "Transform.RotateAround" does. 
but instead of incrementing the angle for each call. 
it should just set the angle to that exact angle like when using "transform.localEulerAngles"

i've been searching for ages now but could not find a good, clean and easy solution.

i already found this: (one of the best "hacks")
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/537155/is-there-a-method-to-set-the-exact-rotation-instea.html

it suggests to reset the rotation before each "Transform.RotateAround" call, but somehow this doesn't work for me and it is not a nice solution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Have you considered just having an empty GameObject centered on the object, with the object to rotate offset within it? That abstracts away that complex calculations involved. I feel like I've addressed variations of this question in the past already, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897629/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901164/). All of them boil down to an empty container object.

Comment: the thing is i want to rotate the same object around many different points at different locations. at a time. more dynamically than making empty containers and offset them.

Comment: If you want to rotate the object around another point, just reposition the container object to be centered at that point, translate the contained object (to adjust the radius of rotation), and rotate it accordingly. Or is there a condition that makes this approach unusable? (That would be relevant to thoroughly explain in the question, since as it stands it doesn't appear very different from the variants I'm looking at.)

Comment: i understand the container object approach. but i was really hoping for a solution that doesn't require me to add and move around containers to all my objects in the scene.
more like a code based solution without changing all the hierarchies of objects and fiddling around in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: revised answer due to misunderstanding

Rotating One object A around another object B involves two steps:

1. Update position of A
2. Update localRoation of A (to keep looking at B with the same side).

This can be achieved with the following example code, where the transform belonging to the script is rotated around the rotationAxis in object B

```
using UnityEngine;

public class rot : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject reference;
    public float angle;
    public Vector3 rotationAxis;
    Vector3 direction;
    void Start () {
        // determine direction only once, to avoid infinite rotation.
        direction = transform.position - reference.transform.position;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, rotationAxis);
        transform.position = reference.transform.position + rot * direction;
        transform.localRotation = rot;
    }
}
```

Comment: this can not work. since it only sets a rotation of the object. to rotate something around something it would also have to change the position of the object.

Comment: Uhm, maybe I don't understand your comment, but that is exactly why I used localRotation. It turns the whole transform around the provided axis (implicitly passing through the pivot point (0, 0, 0) of the transform).
EDIT: Nevermind, now I got it. And I misunderstood your question in the first place. Sorry

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. and in 4 lines of code.
mind blowing. haha